# How can radio button tag in rails be checked according to current value in tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, radio-button, return-value, checked

I have a group of settings for products. For each setting, I want to add a pair of radio button "enabled and "disabled" to represent the setting status. User can click the button to change settings' status in current_setting table. I have two product A and B, the status of all settings related to A are "enabled" and all status of B are "disabled". My problem is that when I refresh the webpage, the radio button checked of A and B are same. All of them are checked on "disabled".

I've tested the following functions: CurrentSetting.setting_enabled? and DefaultSetting.default_enabled?. The test results show that these functions return can return expected results, i.e. the enabled status of all settings related to A are true ("enabled"), for B are false ("disabled"). But the button of A are checked on "disabled".

How can I make radio buttons show the current enabled status of each setting after refresh the webpage? Can someone do me a favor?

The rhtml in view is:

```
     <%@settings.each do |setting|%>
     <%setting_enabled = CurrentSetting.setting_enabled?(@product_id,setting.id)%>
        <!-- Setting on -->
        <%= radio_button_tag("settings[#{setting.key_name}]", "enabled", :checked=> setting_enabled) %>
        <!-- Setting off -->
        <%= radio_button_tag("settings[#{setting.key_name}]", "disabled", :checked=> !setting_enabled) %>
        <%= "#{setting.display_name}" %> 
        <br/>
      <%end%>
```

The function in model current_setting.rb is :

```
     def self.setting_enabled? db_id, default_setting_id
         current_setting = CurrentSetting.find(:first,
                   :conditions => ['db_id = ? and default_setting_id= ? ', db_id, default_setting_id ])

        if  current_setting==nil
           return DefaultSetting.default_enabled?(default_setting_id)   #return default enabled state for this setting 
        else
           return current_setting.enabled
        end 
     end
```

Comment: Do you know/use jquery?  Your problem is simple to explain, correct,  but I only know the solution using jquery

Comment: Sorry, I don't know jquery. But could you tell me the solution using jquery? Maybe I can get some idea.

Comment: Is there any AJAX involved with what you are doing now,  i.e. do you have remote=>true for any links,  forms ?

Comment: Also, I noticed you are using rhtml extension,  quite old,  what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm extending a existed system, which is based on Rails 1.2.3. I have    <%= form_remote_tag :url => 'current_setting/set_settings' %> which will be called after click the save button. <%= submit_tag 'Save Changes' %>

Comment: OUCH!!! 1.2.3!!!,  that's from before I started, like 3+ years ago!!!  I'm not sure I know how to help on a version that old! I barely remember 2.X!

Comment: I also want to use new version. But not lucky. It's hard for me, a beginner of rails, to find the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the comments that you're running a 1.2.x version of rails. So based on that:
http://apidock.com/rails/v1.2.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

```
<%= radio_button_tag("settings[#{setting.key_name}]", "enabled", setting_enabled) %>
<%= radio_button_tag("settings[#{setting.key_name}]", "disabled", !setting_enabled) %>
```